# Colocar imagem fora do container do Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Eu preciso colocar uma imagem fora do container, de forma que a margem do lado direito se mantenha a padrão do container (responsiva), e a imagem se mantenha sempre junta com um "botão".

Segue a imagem abaixo para exemplificar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei utilizar container-fluid (Example 2 - using container-fluid no html), porém não consigo utilizar a mesma margin do container no lado direito. Consigo alterar pelo css, porém teria que alterar para todos os breakpoints, teria outra forma sem precisar disso??

Tentei utilizar o próprio container (Example 3 - using container and margin-left: 0px in html) e tirar o margin-left, sem sucesso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Example 1</h2>
    <div class="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ex1 mt-5">
        <h3>Example 2 - using container-fluid</h3>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-5">
        <h3>Example 3 - using container and margin-left: 0px</h3>
        <div class="container" style="margin-left: 0px">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-6 row">
                    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
                    <div class="col pl-0 mt-5">
                        <div class="nav nav-pills"  aria-orientation="vertical">
                            <a class="nav-link active" >Example1</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alguém saberia alguma forma de fazer, sem que eu tivesse que trocar essa margin-right em todos os breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não imagino para que vc queira um tipo de layout desse, mas é possível fazer usando um mínimo de CSS, Mesmo assim precisei de 1 `breacking point` para tratar a responsividade. No mais o layout ficou como abaixo. Repare que agora eu tenho um *container* pai, com um filho  com a `imagem` e o `btn` dentro e um `.container`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<title>Test</title>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<style>
    .pai {
        position: relative;
    }

    .filho {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .filho {
            position: relative;
        }
    }

</style>
</head>

<body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">col12 Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus molestias sequi nam ducimus reiciendis, a cupiditate velit modi optio, placeat doloremque sint voluptas blanditiis? Consequatur numquam dolorem aspernatur ea molestias.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pai d-flex flex-column flex-md-row">
        <div class="filho d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center mt-5 my-md-auto">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary active">Example1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="container my-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md-6 ml-auto ">
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus sit ipsum ullam, necessitatibus quia laboriosam provident, culpa molestias cum magnam error fugiat voluptatem blanditiis dignissimos modi. Reprehenderit repudiandae nisi dolor?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">col12 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis consectetur reprehenderit quibusdam velit officiis. Atque quod provident consectetur, adipisci commodi explicabo architecto voluptas est expedita, veniam molestias, deserunt cum impedit.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```